# How to filter one dataset based on a column in another dataset in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter, conditional-statements

I have two datasets like this:

```
df1:

A    B
111  0.1
222  0.1
333  0.1

df2:
A    C
111  0.112
222  0.111
```

I want to filter df1 where column A only contain elements that showing in df2 column A, expected result:

```
A    B
111  0.1
222  0.1
```

I have tried this:

```
df1[df1['A'] == df2['A']]

Error:
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

New to Python, can someone gave me some hint, I had a look at other similar questions here but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Did the duplicate answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Josmoor98 Not exactly the same, but I've managed to figure it out, so problem solved, thanks:)